# The 'correct' way to instantiate JPA manager bean?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, websphere-7

I'm using IBM RAD to develop some JPA entities, and from those, corresponding JPA Manager Beans. Manager beans (which are generated by RAD) have the following member:

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

I'm not sure how to correclty instantiate (or get a reference to) this manager bean from a stateless EJB (3.0), so I've added a constructor to manager bean where I can pass `EntityManagerFactory` instance to it. I get a reference to `EntityManagerFactory` in an EJB by using `@PersistenceUnit' annotation like so:

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory _entityManagerFactory;
```

This seems rather unnecessary and I believe there must be a way to tell the container (Websphere 7.0 in my case) to 'bootstrap' this for me somehow, so that I get a reference to JPA manager bean right away. Is it?

**Update:**
It seems I haven't bean elaborate enough. Sorry for that.

- There are three objects involved: JPA Entity, JPA Entity Manager and a Stateless EJB.
- JPA Entity Manager class (not an EJB) is created by RAD and has convinience methods (named queries) on it. It also has defined member `@PersistenceUnit private EntityManagerFactory emf`. I know I can use `EntityManager` directly, but I'd like to use MyEntityManager for it's convinience methods.
- I can get a reference to EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory in a stateless EJB by using annotations described above (and also like Bozho suggests)
- I would like to get a reference to JPA Entity Manager in a stateless EJB. If I 'new' it up  (new MyEntityManager()), the emf field is null. The workaround is to declare @PersistenceUnit field in an EJB and then pass it to JPA Entity Manager and use that.
- Come to think of it, maybe I could declare JPA Entity Manager as an EJB and be done with it... (although this again seems unnecessary). I thought there is a method along the lines PersistenceContext.getJpaManager(MyEntityManager.class) which I am perhaps missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

It seems you have your custom bean that you want to inject in other beans (it needs a local interface at least):

```
@EJB
private MyEntityManager em;
```

Comment: That gets me `EntityManager`, not `MyEntityManager` which depends on `EntityManager` and has actually declared member field like you describe. To put it differently, I'd to know how to get a reference MyEntityManager (which is just a regular bean, annotaed with `@JPAManager`), because if I just `new` it up, @PersistenceContext annotation doesn't work (reference is null). FWIW, I know that I can use EntityManager directly, but MyEntityManager (generated by RAD) has some convience methods and named queries on it which I'd like to reuse.

Comment: I didn't see any reference to MyEntityManager in your question. check update.